# How to fill table using mysql connector in Python 3

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, datatable, mysql-connector

I have data in a text file which I need to upload into a table. My script in python 3 and uses mysql.connector (https://launchpad.net/myconnpy) to connect to DB and execute commands. I have been able successfully use mysql.connector in past without any problems but I am facing problem in using the command that uploads file to a table. My code is as follows:

```
def TableUpload(con2):   
cur = con2.cursor()##Connect to destination server with table
res_file = 'extend2'   
cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE data.results")## Clear table before writing
cur.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './extend2' INTO TABLE data.results FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','")
```

The code clears the table and than try to upload data from text file to table. It successfully clears the table but generated following error while filling table:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "cl3.py", line 575, in <module>
TableUpload(con2)
File "cl3.py", line 547, in TableUpload
cur.execute("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE './extend2' INTO TABLE kakrana_data.mir_page_results FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','")
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 333, in execute
res = self.db().protocol.cmd_query(stmt)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 137, in deco
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/mysql/connector/protocol.py", line 495, in cmd_query
return self.handle_cmd_result(self.conn.recv())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 180, in recv_plain
errors.raise_error(buf)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/mysql/connector/errors.py", line 84, in raise_error
raise get_mysql_exception(errno,errmsg)
mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

When I use the command for uploading file directly from terminal than it works well. It is just that command is not working from script. The error says that command is not allowed with mysql version though it works from terminal. Please suggest what mistake I am making or alternative way to achieve data upload to a table from local file.

Comment: The traceback says you are using Python 2.6.

Comment: @Lev: Thanks for correction but the error is same with python3.